Is it possible to see who made an xml import into a table?
Is there a log or something that saves these import xml modifications made by someone?
in the case of record insertions and overwrites
I looked in the environment, and I didn't find anything that showed me that. As if making this change were invisible.

if you:

Go to System Logs > Transactions (All User)
Make sure the URL and Created by fields are in your list view
Look for "upload.do" in the URL field around the time you think the XML record was imported

You will find all user transactions for imported XML files.
The upload.do page is what a user would have called to import an XML file from a list view.
I hope this helps.
Lucas Vieties

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
